# e._d.getTime is not a function

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I downloaded with your calendar and I went straight to the factory.
However, I now get the following error in updateEvent in the console:

`TypeError: e._d.getTime is not a function`

this is my code:

```
var CalenderEvent;
var datenPruefenDatenSenden;
var terminPruefenDatenSenden;
var datenPruefenDatenVerarbeiten;
$(document).ready(function() {
    function DeleteEvent(id){
        SendFormData(id,'',"delete");
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',id);
    }
    var initialLocaleCode = 'de';
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
        },
        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#calenderAdEvent').modal('show');
        },
        eventRender: function(eventObj, $el) {
            $el.popover({
                title: eventObj.title,
                content: eventObj.description,
                trigger: 'hover',
                placement: 'top',
                container: 'body'
            });
            $el.html(eventObj.title + '<span class="removebtn" onclick="DeleteEvent('+eventObj.id+');" id="Delete">X</span>');
            $el.find(".removebtn").click(function() {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',eventObj.id);
            });
        },
        businessHours: [
             { dow: [ 1 ], start: '07:00', end: '20:00' } , { dow: [ 2 ], start: '07:00', end: '20:00' } , { dow: [ 3 ], start: '07:00', end: '20:00' } , { dow: [ 4 ], start: '07:00', end: '20:00' } , { dow: [ 5 ], start: '00:00', end: '00:00' } , { dow: [ 6 ], start: '00:00', end: '00:00' } , { dow: [ 7 ], start: '00:00', end: '00:00' }             ],
        eventDrop: function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
            var Alertback = SendFormData(event.id,$.fullCalendar.moment(event.start._d), $.fullCalendar.moment(event.end._d),"update");
            alert(Alertback);
        },
        eventResize: function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) { 
            var Alertback = SendFormData(event.id,$.fullCalendar.moment(event.start._d), $.fullCalendar.moment(event.end._d),"update");
            alert(Alertback);
        },
        timezone: 'Europe/Berlin',
        nowIndicator: true,
        now: '2018-11-13T21:47:41',
        locale: 'de',
        buttonIcons: true, // show the prev/next text
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        defaultDate: '2018-11-13',
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        allDaySlot: true,
        droppable: true,
        events: [

            {
              start: 1546884000000,
              end: 1546887600000,
              title: 'Nails Grundmodellage',
              description: 'Schlegel Cassandra',
              id: '1',
              TimeEvent: '1:00:00'
            }
        ,
            {
              start: 1546968600000,
              end: 1546974000000,
              title: 'Kosmetik 1,5h',
              description: 'Hempel Gabriele',
              id: '2',
              TimeEvent: '1:50:00'
            }
        ,
            {
              start: 1542362460000,
              end: 1542373500000,
              title: 'Nails Grundmodellage',
              description: 'Laufer2 Eric2',
              id: '20',
              TimeEvent: '1:00:00'
            }
        ,
            {
              start: 1542279660000,
              end: 1542297660000,
              title: 'Nails Grundmodellage',
              description: 'Laufer2 Eric2',
              id: '21',
              TimeEvent: '1:00:00'
            }
                    ],
        timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
        eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            CalenderEvent = event;
            $('#id_termin').val(event.id);
            $('#name').val(event.title);
            $('#Time_Event').val(event.TimeEvent);
            $('#description').val(event.description);
            $('#start_date_day').val(moment(event.start).format('DD.MM.YYYY'));
            $('#start_date_time').val(moment(event.start).format('HH:mm'));
            if(event.end) {
                $('#end_date_day').val(moment(event.end).format('DD.MM.YYYY'));
                $('#end_date_time').val(moment(event.end).format('HH:mm'));
            } else {
                $('#end_date_day').val(moment(event.end).format('DD.MM.YYYY'));
                $('#end_date_time').val(moment(event.end).format('HH:mm'));
            }
            $('#event_id').val(event.id);
            $('#calenderEditEvent').modal();
        }
    });

    datenPruefenDatenSenden = function(){
        var start = $('#start_date_day').val()+'//'+$('#start_date_time').val();
        var end = $('#end_date_day').val()+'//'+$('#end_date_time').val();
        var erg = SendFormData($("#id_termin").val(),start,end,'TerminEditSave');
        var sta = $('#start_date_day').val().split(".");
        var ende = $('#start_date_day').val().split(".");
        $('#calenderEditEvent').modal('hide');
        console.log(sta[2]+'-'+sta[1]+'-'+sta[0]+'T'+$('#start_date_time').val());
        CalenderEvent.start._d = $.fullCalendar.moment(sta[2]+'-'+sta[1]+'-'+sta[0]+'T'+$('#start_date_time').val());
        CalenderEvent.end._d = $.fullCalendar.moment(ende[2]+'-'+ende[1]+'-'+ende[0]+'T'+$('#start_date_time').val());
        console.log(CalenderEvent.start._d);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', CalenderEvent);
    }

    datenPruefenDatenVerarbeiten = function (daten){
        if(daten == 1){$('#submit_erg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">Termin&uuml;berschneidung</div><button class="btn btn-info" onclick="terminPruefenDatenSenden();">Erneut pr&uuml;fen</button>');}
        $('#submit_button').html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="datenPruefenDatenSenden();">Termin Speichern</button>');
    }

    terminPruefenDatenSenden = function (){
        $('#submit_erg').html('');
        var start = $('#start_date_day').val()+'//'+$('#start_date_time').val();
        var end = $('#end_date_day').val()+'//'+$('#end_date_time').val();
        var erg = SendFormData($("#id_termin").val(),start,end,'pruefen');
    }

    function termin_nachberechnung(){
        var TimePlus = new Hour($('#Time_Event').val());
        var zeit = new Hour($('#start_date_time').val()+':00');
        $('#end_date_time').val(zeit.add(TimePlus));
    }
});

$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="datepicker_bearbeiten"]').datepicker({
    autoHide: true,
    format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
    zIndex: 2048,
  });
});

function SendFormData(id,start,end,aufruf){
    var erg;
    if(aufruf == 'update'){start = start/1000;end = end/1000;}
    $.ajax({type: "post",url: "kalender2/kalender.class.php",data : {id : id,sta : start,end : end,aufruf : aufruf}
    }).done(function( dataEnd ){if(aufruf == 'pruefen'){datenPruefenDatenVerarbeiten(dataEnd);}erg = dataEnd;});
    return erg;
}
```

I have read the events as seen here and then let them call via button and eventClick. then check this with php and then gives the signal if the update is possible or not.
It all works to the last point.
also the date is written correctly and spent in the console. unfortunately, then $ ('# calendar') will return. fullCalendar ('updateEvent', CalenderEvent); this line has an error and no update is made. as soon as I take the date out and let only the title change and go through the update, it goes again.
I have no idea what's wrong with the date.

Comment: `$.fullCalendar.moment(event.start._d)` is really pointless - event.start is already a moment. You don't need to make it into another moment again (especially not by trying to read what is meant to be an internal property of the moment object). Just send event.start directly. P.S. if you're going to then send these dates in a post request, you might want to [format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) them explicitly into a suitable, unambiguous format that your server can read, otherwise you leave it to whatever momentJS decides to stringify it to.

Comment: `CalenderEvent.start._d = $.fullCalendar.moment(sta[2]+'-'+sta[1]+'-'+sta[0]+'T'+$('#start_date_time').val());
        CalenderEvent.end._d = $.fullCalendar.moment(ende[2]+'-'+ende[1]+'-'+ende[0]+'T'+$('#start_date_time').val());
` Likewise these lines make no sense and are massively overcomplicating things. fullCalendar can read a momentJS object directly...you don't need to mess about concatenating bits of strings together. `CalendarEvent.start = sta` will do the trick (if `$('#start_date_day').val()` returns something automatically parseable). Stop using `._d`, it's not meant to be used.

Comment: If it doesn't return something [automatically parseable](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/), then use [this](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) in momentJS to tell it what format to expect. e.g. `CalendarEvent.start = moment($('#start_date_day').val(), "DD.MM.YYYY");` or whatever your format is.

Comment: thank you for your help. Now it's finally time. :-)